# 3 wire cooktop, 4 wire stove, 4 wire supply - what to do about neutral and ground?

Tags: wiring

The supply has black, red, white and ground. So does the stove. The cooktop only has black, red and ground. What do I do with the white wire from the stove? Connect it to the white on the supply, or combine it with the ground?

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: That's an  easy one, because neutral and ground are both supplied.  It gets harder in older installations without ground.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you connect like to like.

The cooktop does not have a neutral (white) wire.

This is perfectly fine. The cooktop has no 120Volt loads, so it does not NEED a white wire.

*[ The concerning case is when an old device has black, red, & white, but no ground (green or bare) ]*